# Executing command prompt in java

Tags: java

i am executing these commands in java and i am getting following error

```
symbol  : method write(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.OutputStream
out.write("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\".getBytes()+filename+" --db-username IIP_RBM_USER --db-password Ytpqxsb9dw".getBytes());



String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

out.write("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\".getBytes()+filename+" --db-username IIP_R --db-password Ytb9dw".getBytes());

How Do i resolve this issue.
```

Comment: Don't use a single `String` for the commands, spaces screw things up.  Instead, pass each parameter as a separate `String` and use `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStream` except a `byte[]`, not a `String`:

```
out.write("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\".getBytes() +
           filename + " --db-username IIP_R --db-password Ytb9dw".getBytes());
```

I don't think `javac` would allow `"...".getBytes() + String` as it is a `byte[] + String`. And the + operator is defined for `Number`, `String` and `boolean`. Not `byte[]`.

Instead you must:

- either use a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) over your Stream.
- either concatenate first to a String, then call getBytes on the result.

With PrintStream:

```
try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(child.getOutputStream())) {
  ps.append("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\")
    .append(filename)
    .append(" --db-username IIP_R --db-password Ytb9dw");
}
```

With `String` concatenation:

```
out.write( ("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\" +
            filename + " --db-username IIP_R --db-password Ytb9dw").getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
```

I use [`getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and not [`getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29), but that depends on your process (eg: does it accept UTF-8 ?). You must however remember that Java String are Unicode sequence and thus, getBytes() might use *Windows cp1252* (default on Windows).

I did not check in the `PrintStream` source code, but if it use `getBytes()` without a `Charset`, then use you should use a [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) with appropriate charset.